# Read a Fixed Length position based file and insert into a oracle Table in Java

Tags: java, sql, rest, file, jakarta-ee

Currently I am working on a solution to read a 454 character/line based huge file (minimum 50000 rows) via Java.As per the requirement it is a positioned based file, we first need to read the file , then parse the position based values and need to insert into a table. (minimum 96 positions will be inserted into 96 columns of the table).

I took this concept after the parsing.

```
[ INSERT ALL INTO<TABLE NAME> [COL1,COL2,COL3] Values [VAL1,VAL2,VAL3]
                INTO<TABLE NAME> [COL1,COL2,COL3] Values [VAL1,VAL2,VAL3]
SELECT * FROM DUAL;]
```

Here is my code:

```
try{
    char[] line = new char[456];
    while(br.read(line) > 0){ 
        StringBuilder input = new StringBuilder(new   String(line));

        if(batchCounter>0){
            int detailFileId = interfaceFileSequence();
            sql.append(initSql+"(" + 
                detailFileId + "," + interfaceHeaderId + ", SYSDATE," +
                interfaceRunId + "," + isSpace(input.substring(0, 2).trim()) + "," + "TO_DATE("+isSpace(input.substring(2, 12).trim())+",'YYYY-MM-DD')" +","+isSpace(input.substring(12, 22).trim()) + "," + 
                Double.parseDouble(input.substring(22, 35)+ "." + input.substring(35, 37)) + ", " + 
                Double.parseDouble(input.substring(22, 35)+ "." + input.substring(35, 37)) + ", " + 
                isSpace(input.substring(38, 44).trim()) + ","+isSpace(input.substring(38, 44).trim())+"," +isSpace(input.substring(38, 44).trim())+"," + isSpace(input.substring(44, 54).trim())+","+

                isSpace(input.substring(54, 60).trim()) + "," + isSpace(input.substring(60, 68).trim()) + "," + isSpace(input.substring(68, 83).trim()) + "," + 
                isSpace(input.substring(83, 89).trim()) + "," + isSpace(input.substring(89, 94).trim()) + "," + 
                isSpace(input.substring(94, 102).trim()) + "," + 
                isSpace(input.substring(102, 103).trim()) + ","+"TO_DATE("+isSpace(input.substring(103,113).trim())+",'YYYY-MM-DD')"+"," +isSpace(input.substring(113, 125).trim()) + "," + isSpace(input.substring(125, 128).trim()) + "," + 
                isSpace(input.substring(131, 133).trim()) + "," + isSpace(input.substring(133, 135).trim()) + "," + isSpace(input.substring(135, 136).trim()) + "," + 
                isSpace(input.substring(136, 137).trim()) + "," + isSpace(input.substring(137, 142).trim()) + "," + isSpace(input.substring(142, 147).trim()) + "," + 
                isSpace(input.substring(147, 148).trim()) + "," + isSpace(input.substring(149, 159).trim()) + "," +  
                isSpace(input.substring(159, 160).trim()) + "," + isSpace(input.substring(160, 175).trim()) + "," + isSpace(input.substring(160, 175).trim()) + "," +

                isSpace(input.substring(190, 220).trim()) +"," +"TO_DATE("+isSpace(input.substring(216, 220)+"-"+input.substring(220, 222)+"-"+input.substring(222, 224))+",'YYYY-MM-DD')"+","+
                "TO_DATE("+isSpace(input.substring(216, 220)+"-"+input.substring(220, 222)+"-"+input.substring(222, 224))+",'YYYY-MM-DD')"+","+ isSpace(input.substring(226,227).trim()) + "," + isSpace(input.substring(231,236).trim()) + "," + 
                isSpace(input.substring(242, 245).trim()) + "," + isSpace(input.substring(245,275).trim()) + "," + isSpace(input.substring(275,280).trim()) + "," + 
                isSpace(input.substring(280, 290).trim()) + "," + isSpace(input.substring(290,293).trim()) + "," + isSpace(input.substring(293,303).trim()) + "," + 
                isSpace(input.substring(303, 314).trim()) + "," + 
                isSpace(input.substring(313,316).trim()) +  //need check
                "," + isSpace(input.substring(317,337).trim()) + "," +

                isSpace(input.substring(337, 422).trim()) + 
                "," + isSpace(input.substring(422,433).trim()) + "," + isSpace(input.substring(433,443).trim())+","+isSpace(input.substring(22, 39).trim())+
                ")");
            sql.append('\n');
        }

        /*if (batchCounter % 500 == 0) {
            System.out.println("sql:::::::::::"+sql);
            int executeUpdate = em.createNativeQuery(sql.toString()).executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("executeUpdateexecu:::"+executeUpdate);
            em.flush();
            insertionCounter += executeUpdate;
            System.out.println("insertionCounter::::"+insertionCounter);
            sql.setLength(0);
            System.out.println("SQL");
            System.out.println("initSql"+initSql);
            sql.append(initSql);
        }*/

        batchCounter++; 
    } 

        sql.append("  SELECT * FROM dual");


    int executeUpdate = em.createNativeQuery(sql.toString()).executeUpdate();
    em.flush();
    insertionCounter += executeUpdate;
    System.out.println("Check Rows in file::"+(batchCounter-1)+"  Insertion counter::"+insertionCounter);
    if((batchCounter-1)==insertionCounter){
        detailFileObj = new DetailFileObject(FileName, "DETAIL", (batchCounter-1), "SUCCESS");
    }
    else {
        detailFileObj = new DetailFileObject(FileName, "DETAIL", (batchCounter-1), "FAILED");
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But once I am running the code, if there are 40-50 lines, it is working fine.But it is more than that I am getting exception. Can anyone share me proper approach along with running code, so that I can use it.
Thanks

Comment: What's the exception?  Post the stack trace.

Comment: Timeout exception is giving. Moreover we are calling this function from REST-WS.

Comment: Probably need to move the code to an async task so the REST call can return immediately, where the initial call returns a response as "started".  Then provide another REST endpoint where the client can occasionally call to get status/progress.

Comment: Yes. That is good suggestion. But after this load, we need other process based on load result and how do client will get info that load is completed or not. Moreover they way we are parsing and inserting is there any better approach.

Comment: The status endpoint returns the current progress - for example a JSON with properties _status_ with values of "working", "completed" and "error", along with _processedCount_ that can be displayed by the client.  The end of the load task could trigger another async task, or schedule a task to run sometime in the future.  The other part is more of a code review which should be posted [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

First, DO NOT use string concatenation to build a SQL statement with text values from outside. It leaves you susceptible to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks, and may cause SQL syntax errors. Use a [`PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) with `?` parameter markers instead.

Second, if you're inserting a lot of records, use JDBC batching.

Here is an example of how you would use it:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO MyTable" +
            " ( Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7 )" +
            " VALUES (?,?,SYSDATE,?,?,?,?)";
try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    char[] line = new char[456];
    int batchSize = 0;
    while (br.read(line) > 0) {
        String input = new String(line);
        int detailFileId = interfaceFileSequence();
        stmt.setInt   (1, detailFileId);
        stmt.setInt   (2, interfaceHeaderId);
        stmt.setInt   (3, interfaceRunId);
        stmt.setString(4, toString(input.substring(0, 2)));
        stmt.setDate  (5, toDate(input.substring(2, 12)));
        stmt.setString(6, toString(input.substring(12, 22)));
        // ...
        stmt.addBatch();
        if (++batchSize == 1000) {
            stmt.executeBatch();
            batchSize = 0;
        }
    }
    if (batchSize != 0) {
        stmt.executeBatch();
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The above code uses the following helper methods to keep code [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself):

```
private static String toString(String text) {
    String trimmed = text.trim();
    return (trimmed.isEmpty() ? null : trimmed);
}
private static java.sql.Date toDate(String text) {
    String trimmed = text.trim();
    return (trimmed.isEmpty() ? null : java.sql.Date.valueOf(LocalDate.parse(trimmed)));
}
```

Comment: I agree with the recommendations, only I’d use `stmt.setObject()` to set a modern `LocalDate` rather than an old-fashioned `java.sql.Date`. This will also save you a conversion in `toDate()`.